# TikZ - Node fit over multiple matrix cells does not want to align vertically

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to align the top line of the node named `ImportantStuff` along the upper line of  `AlsoImportantStuff`'s upper line. How can I do that?

### Picture

[image]

### MWE (new)

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    external,
    plotmarks,
    calc,
    matrix,
    intersections,
    fit
}

\tikzset{
hauptgruppe/.style={
    rectangle,
    minimum width=1cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries,
    draw=black,
    very thick,
    fill=white,
},
infotext/.style={
    draw=black,
    rectangle,
    font=\sffamily\footnotesize,
    align=left,
},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\matrix [
matrix of nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
row sep=5pt,
column sep=5pt,
inner sep=5pt,
row 1/.style={nodes={hauptgruppe}},
%row 2/.style={nodes={infotext, text width=0.25\linewidth, align=center}},
name=m,
]
{
    | (asdf)| {\parbox[t]{1.8cm}{AAAA}\hfill\parbox[t]{1.8cm}{BBBB}} &
    | (dfgdsfgadgf)| {BBBB} &
    | (regf3refg)| {BBBB} \\
    | [infotext, text width=0.25\linewidth, font=\sffamily\footnotesize, anchor=north] (ImportantStuff) | {%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item{AAA}
        \item{BBB}
        \item{CCC}
        \item{Arbitrary words. Who knows how much text exactly\ldots}
        \item{\ldots gets puts here\ldots}
%       \item{See?}
        \end{itemize}} & |[minimum width=0.25\linewidth, minimum height=2cm, anchor=north]| ~ & |[minimum width=0.25\linewidth, minimum height=1cm, anchor=north]| ~ \\
};
\node[infotext, font=\sffamily\footnotesize, text width=0.5\linewidth, fit=(m-2-2) (m-2-3), anchor=north] (AlsoImportantStuff){%
    \begin{itemize}
    \item{Longer text to make it worth it.}
    \item{And some words}
    \item{Even more}
    \end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

### MWE (old), necessary if you like to understand the solution

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    external,
    plotmarks,
    calc,
    matrix,
    intersections,
    fit
}

\tikzset{
hauptgruppe/.style={
    rectangle,
    minimum width=1cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries,
    draw=black,
    very thick,
    fill=white,
},
gruppe/.style={
    rectangle,
    minimum width=2cm,
    minimum height=0.8cm,
    draw=gray,
    very thick,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries,
},
untergruppe/.style={
    rectangle,
    minimum width=2cm,
    minimum height=1cm, 
    text width=3.5cm,
    draw=gray,
    very thick,
    font=\sffamily,
},
infotext/.style={
    draw=black,
    rectangle,
    font=\sffamily\footnotesize,
    align=left,
},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\matrix [
matrix of nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
row sep=5pt,
column sep=5pt,
inner sep=5pt,
row 1/.style={nodes={hauptgruppe}},
row 2/.style={nodes={infotext, text width=0.25\linewidth, align=center}},
%row 3/.style={nodes={infotext, text width=0.25\linewidth, font=\sffamily\footnotesize}},
row 4/.style={nodes={infotext, text width=0.25\linewidth, font=\sffamily\footnotesize}},
name=m,
%below=2cm of 
]
{
    | (ergergt3gdfg) | {Word} &
    | (efgsdfhdahf) | {Yo} &
    | (3fefgdsf) | {Lo} \\
    | (erg4zdhfsz)| {\parbox[t]{1.8cm}{AAAA}\hfill\parbox[t]{1.8cm}{BBBB}} &
    | (ElastomereBedhfwjeoifjwgispiel)| {BBBB} &
    | (woiefs9djfo)| {BBBB} \\
    | [infotext, text width=0.25\linewidth, font=\sffamily\footnotesize, anchor=north] (ImportantStuff) | {%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item{AAA}
        \item{BBB}
        \item{CCC}
        \item{Arbitrary words. Who knows how much text exactly\ldots}
        \item{\ldots gets puts here\ldots}
%       \item{See?}
        \end{itemize}} & |[minimum width=0.25\linewidth, minimum height=2cm, anchor=north]| ~ & |[minimum width=0.25\linewidth, minimum height=1cm, anchor=north]| ~ \\
    | (XXXXenschaften) | {%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item{A}
        \item{B}
        \item{C}
        \end{itemize}} &
    | (YYYYYY) | {%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item{A}
        \item{B}
        \item{C}
        \end{itemize}} &
    | (ZZZZZ) | {%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item{A}
        \item{B}
        \item{C}
        \end{itemize}}\\
};
\node[infotext, font=\sffamily\footnotesize, text width=0.5\linewidth, fit=(m-3-2) (m-3-3), anchor=north] (AlsoImportantStuff){%
    \begin{itemize}
    \item{Longer text to make it worth it.}
    \item{And some words}
    \item{Even more}
    \end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If just needed once: `anchor=north, yshift=28.65pt] (AlsoImportantStuff)` does the trick...

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Ah, those elusive `28.65pt`. I've been yearning for the day I could use them. ... on a more serious note, how did you come up with that value?

Comment: I suggested that the upper boarder of my PDF-reader is completely horizontal and started some hours of bovine trial-and-error. (on a more serious note: "...there's way too much information to decode the Matrix. You get used to it, though. Your brain does the translating. I don't even see the code.")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to place the upper left corner (i.e: its `north west` anchor) of the box `AlsoImportantStuff` at the point which is the intersection of the horizontal line passing through `ImportantStuff.north` and the vertical line passing through `ElastomereBedhfwjeoifjwgispiel.west`, so you can translate these specifications into tikz language with:

```
\node[infotext, font=\sffamily\footnotesize, text width=0.5\linewidth, fit=(m-3-2) (m-3-3), 
    anchor=north west]                                             % <-------
    at (ImportantStuff.north-|ElastomereBedhfwjeoifjwgispiel.west) % <-------
    (AlsoImportantStuff){%                                                                     
    \begin{itemize}                                                                           
    \item{Longer text to make it worth it.}                                                   
    \item{And some words}                                                                     
    \item{Even more}                                                                          
    \end{itemize}};
```

Which produces:

[image: Result]

Yes, I notice that the width of the box is slightly shorter than it should, but this is something related to the tikz styles you defined, not to the question asked :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to adjust the `inner/outer sep` respectively. The current position is th default value 0pt. This solution shows adding 
inner sep=4.5pt, outer sep=-28pt will align top while outer sep=30pt will align bottom

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    external,
    plotmarks,
    calc,
    matrix,
    intersections,
    fit
}

\tikzset{
hauptgruppe/.style={
    rectangle,
    minimum width=1cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries,
    draw=black,
    very thick,
    fill=white,
},
gruppe/.style={
    rectangle,
    minimum width=2cm,
    minimum height=0.8cm,
    draw=gray,
    very thick,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries,
},
untergruppe/.style={
    rectangle,
    minimum width=2cm,
    minimum height=1cm, 
    text width=3.5cm,
    draw=gray,
    very thick,
    font=\sffamily,
},
infotext/.style={
    draw=black,
    rectangle,
    font=\sffamily\footnotesize,
    align=left,
},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\matrix [
matrix of nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
row sep=5pt,
column sep=5pt,
inner sep=5pt,
row 1/.style={nodes={hauptgruppe}},
row 2/.style={nodes={infotext, text width=0.25\linewidth, align=center}},
%row 3/.style={nodes={infotext, text width=0.25\linewidth, font=\sffamily\footnotesize}},
row 4/.style={nodes={infotext, text width=0.25\linewidth, font=\sffamily\footnotesize}},
name=m,
%below=2cm of 
]
{
    | (ergergt3gdfg) | {Word} &
    | (efgsdfhdahf) | {Yo} &
    | (3fefgdsf) | {Lo} \\
    | (erg4zdhfsz)| {\parbox[t]{1.8cm}{AAAA}\hfill\parbox[t]{1.8cm}{BBBB}} &
    | (ElastomereBedhfwjeoifjwgispiel)| {BBBB} &
    | (woiefs9djfo)| {BBBB} \\
    | [infotext, text width=0.25\linewidth, font=\sffamily\footnotesize, anchor=north] (ImportantStuff) | {%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item{AAA}
        \item{BBB}
        \item{CCC}
        \item{Arbitrary words. Who knows how much text exactly\ldots}
        \item{\ldots gets puts here\ldots}
%       \item{See?}
        \end{itemize}} & |[minimum width=0.25\linewidth, minimum height=2cm, anchor=north]| ~ & |[minimum width=0.25\linewidth, minimum height=1cm, anchor=north]| ~ \\
    | (XXXXenschaften) | {%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item{A}
        \item{B}
        \item{C}
        \end{itemize}} &
    | (YYYYYY) | {%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item{A}
        \item{B}
        \item{C}
        \end{itemize}} &
    | (ZZZZZ) | {%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item{A}
        \item{B}
        \item{C}
        \end{itemize}}\\
};
\node[infotext, font=\sffamily\footnotesize, text width=0.5\linewidth, fit=(m-3-2) (m-3-3), anchor=north, inner sep=4.5pt,outer sep=-28pt] (AlsoImportantStuff){%
    \begin{itemize}
    \item{Longer text to make it worth it.}
    \item{And some words}
    \item{Even more}
    \end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which is the most straight-forward imho. It is based on @JLDiaz's answer which worked in the first place but I kept going at it.

### Picture

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    external,
    plotmarks,
    calc,
    matrix,
    intersections,
    fit
}

\tikzset{
hauptgruppe/.style={
    rectangle,
    minimum width=1cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries,
    draw=black,
    very thick,
    fill=white,
},
infotext/.style={
    draw=black,
    rectangle,
    font=\sffamily\footnotesize,
    align=left,
},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\matrix [
matrix of nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
row sep=5pt,
column sep=5pt,
inner sep=5pt,
row 1/.style={nodes={hauptgruppe}},
%row 2/.style={nodes={infotext, text width=0.25\linewidth, align=center}},
name=m,
]
{
    | (asdf)| {\parbox[t]{1.8cm}{AAAA}\hfill\parbox[t]{1.8cm}{BBBB}} &
    | (dfgdsfgadgf)| {BBBB} &
    | (regf3refg)| {BBBB} \\
    | [infotext, text width=0.25\linewidth, font=\sffamily\footnotesize, anchor=north] (ImportantStuff) | {%
        \begin{itemize}
        \item{AAA}
        \item{BBB}
        \item{CCC}
        \item{Arbitrary words. Who knows how much text exactly\ldots}
        \item{\ldots gets puts here\ldots}
%       \item{See?}
        \end{itemize}} & |[minimum width=0.25\linewidth, minimum height=2cm, anchor=north]| ~ & |[minimum width=0.25\linewidth, minimum height=1cm, anchor=north]| ~ \\
};
%old
%\node[infotext, font=\sffamily\footnotesize, text width=0.5\linewidth, fit=(m-2-2) (m-2-3), anchor=north] (AlsoImportantStuff){%
%the solution
\node[infotext, font=\sffamily\footnotesize, text width=0.5\linewidth, fit=(m-2-2) (m-2-3), anchor=north west, minimum height=1.5cm, xshift=5pt] at (ImportantStuff.north east|-m-2-2.north west) {%
    \begin{itemize}
    \item{Longer text to make it worth it.}
    \item{And some words}
    \item{Even more}
    \end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```